# How to maintain character encoding of database query

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon

Within a Firefox extension, I am opening a database file and displaying the database contents.  However, Firefox is showing some characters incorrectly, presumably due to an encoding issue.  I tried opening the database file in SQLite Database Browser and the name column displayed correctly.

How can I properly handle this text string so that it outputs characters as I intended (e.g., `Caché` rather than `CachÃ©`)?

Code snippet which reproduces this problem:

```
var StorageService = Cc["@mozilla.org/storage/service;1"]
    .getService(Ci.mozIStorageService);
_Conn = StorageService.openDatabase(file);
var stmt = _Conn.createStatement("Select name from data");
var RunQuery = function () {
    return {
        arr: [],
        handleResult: function (aResultSet) {
            var row = aResultSet.getNextRow();
            alert([row.getResultByName("name"), 'Cach\u00E9']);
        },
        handleError: function (aError) {},
        handleCompletion: function (aReason) {}
    };
};
stmt.executeAsync(RunQuery());
```

Output: `CachÃ©,Caché`
Intended Output: `Caché,Caché`

Comment: You have to convert the strings from UTF-8 to whatever encoding Firefox expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var converter = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"]
    .createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
converter.charset = "UTF-8";
alert([converter.ConvertToUnicode(row.getString("name")), 'Cach\u00E9']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming IDX_NAME is the index of column `name`, then

```
alert([row.getUTF8String(IDX_NAME), 'Cach\u00E9']);
```

will give you the intended result.

Comment: Surprisingly, this gave the same output as `alert([row.getResultByName("name"), 'Cach\u00E9']);` Note that SQLite Database Browser does state that my database is UTF8 encoded.